# maven: how to remove a dependency from all modules of a project

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have to clean up a project which has a huge number of modules. Now there is a superflous dependency in all (or maybe most) of those module poms, which I want to remove. Is there an easy way to do so?

To give some more context: The version of this dependency is managed in the parent pom (in dependencyManagement). So removing the version makes the modules non-buildable. Don't know, if that may help somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i dont know how handy todays search&replace tools are (where you would search for your dependency entry and replace it with a empty String) but unless a huge number is like a quadrillion modules i would just remove the `dependencyManagement` section to have the build fail and then remove the dependencie wherever the version-information is missing.

As faar as i know there is no Plugin available to remove dependencies from all pom.xmls hence i would not see this as a typical Maven task but more or less a typical search&replace in multiple files of multiple folders task.